# How can I verify the legitimacy of the CDF for a given function by checking whether it is non-decreasing or not?

Tags: r

```
\[\begin{array}{l}
a)F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,x \le 0\\
\frac{{{x^3}}}{8},0 < x < 2\\
1,x \ge 2
\end{array} \right.\\
b)F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,x \le 0\\
{x^2} + 2x,x > 0
\end{array} \right.\\
c)F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,x \le 0\\
{e^{\frac{{ - 1}}{x}}},x > 0
\end{array} \right.\\
d)F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,x \le  - 1\\
{x^2} - 1, - 1 < x < \sqrt 2 \\
1,x \ge \sqrt 2 
\end{array} \right.\\
e)F(x) = \frac{{{e^x}}}{{1 + {e^x}}}, - \infty  < x < \infty 
\end{array}\]
```

Based on the PDF, we plot the CDF,

```
        knitr::include_graphics("Q5a.png")
```

[image]

Based on the fact that the CDF is non decreasing when it reaches x=2, it is a legitimate CDF

Comment: I need help to plot these functions in R so that I do not have to do it by hand and prove them clearly

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow doesn't render LaTeX. Would you post your euqations as an image? And also show what you've tried in R and explain where you are stuck.